# Automatic error conversion using the '?' operator for custom types

Tags: rust, type-conversion, traits, trait-objects

I'm struggling to understand the nuances of the `?` operator. Take the following code:

[link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8108b0fd133ec6de5befe01162a56190)

```
use std::{error::Error as StdError, fmt};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyError(Box<dyn StdError>);

impl fmt::Display for MyError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        fmt::Debug::fmt(self, f)
    }
}

impl StdError for MyError{}

impl From<Box<dyn StdError>> for MyError {
    fn from(err: Box<dyn StdError>) -> Self {
        MyError(err)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct RandomErr(String);

impl fmt::Display for RandomErr {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        fmt::Debug::fmt(self, f)
    }
}

impl StdError for RandomErr{}

fn no_custom() -> Result<(), Box<dyn StdError>> {
    Err(RandomErr("hello there".to_owned()))?
}

// This fails to compile
fn custom() -> Result<(), MyError> {
    Err(RandomErr("hello there".to_owned()))?
}
```

I would think that `custom()` should compile. `RandomError` is a `StdError`, so `RandomErr` should be convertable to `MyError` since there's an impl for converting from `StdError`, no?

Answer (score 3):

> I would think that `custom()` should compile. `RandomError` is a `StdError`, so `RandomErr` should be convertable to `MyError` since there's an impl for converting from `StdError`, no?

Nope. There is no transitivity in `From` (or any trait, as far as I know). Rustc generally does what you tell it *and no more* to avoid problems like combinatory explosions in trait resolution.

So that `C: From<B>` and `B: From<A>` does not imply / translate to `C: From<A>`, you can write that reduced case and will hit E0277 (trait not satisfied):

```rust
struct A;
struct B;
struct C;

impl From<A> for B {
    fn from(a: A) -> Self { B }
}
impl From<B> for C {
    fn from(b: B) -> Self { C }
}

fn main() {
    let _: C = From::from(A);
}
```